# How to properly debug PHP curl_setopt_array when it's returing false?

Tags: php, curl

Code:

```
<?php
  $this->curlHandle = curl_init();

  $curl_options = $this->additionalCurlOptions + array(
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $this->cookieFile,
    CURLOPT_URL => $base_url,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 5,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE, // Required to make the tests run on https.
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE, // Required to make the tests run on https.
    CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION => array(&$this, 'curlHeaderCallback'),
  );
  if (isset($this->httpauth_credentials)) {
    $curl_options[CURLOPT_USERPWD] = $this->httpauth_credentials;
  }

  // curl_setopt_array() returns FALSE if any of the specified options
  // cannot be set, and stops processing any further options.
  $result = curl_setopt_array($this->curlHandle, $this->additionalCurlOptions + $curl_options);
?>
```

I need to figure out what's going wrong with those curl options. How to debug the `curl_setopt_array()` itself? Since the cookiejar is a (tested) working filename, url is correct, the header function is working, and every other option is hard-coded, what should i do to dig deeper?

Answer (score 1):

You should use plural `curl_setopt` instead of singular `curl_setopt_array` for debugging.